# XSLT strip space for output=text

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I am transforming an XML document into JSON using XSLT. There is some content in the XML file that looks like the following:

```
  <Date>
Thursday, November 8th
</Date>
```

The break in space hurts when I put the string into a JSON parser. It would work much better if it was coming in through as

`<Date>Thursday, November 8th</Date>`

I figured one solution that might work would be to add the following after my output tag:

```
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/message">
     <xsl:variable name="date"><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></xsl:variable>
```

Unfortunately that isn't affecting my output and still adding the additional space when I add the following:

```
 {
   "date": "<xsl:value-of select="$date"/>"
 }
```

it still ends up parsing with the spaces and line breaks which breaks the JSON parser.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `normalize-space`

```
"date": "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($date)"/>"
```